# python regular expressions returns wrong result

Tags: python, regex

Below is my code:

```
import re
str = "?CNTN_CD=A0002400127&PAGE_CD=ET00_1&BLCK_NO=1&CMPT_CD=T0016&TEXT=한글패러미터"
pattern = re.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9?=&\-_]+")
result = pattern.search(str)
print(result)
```

This is the result:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 65), match='?CNTN_CD=A0002400127&PAGE_CD=ET00_1&BLCK_NO=1&CMP>
```

But I expect this result:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 65), match='?CNTN_CD=A0002400127&PAGE_CD=ET00_1&BLCK_NO=1&CMPT_CD=T0016&TEXT=>
```

I can't find reason for that result. Please give me advice.

Thanks you very much.

Comment: your string variable is str or str3?

Comment: I'm sorry. It's str.

Comment: avoid using `str` as variable name... it is a keyword https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Answer (score 0):

You may use this:

```
[\u0000-\u007F]+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9idExf/1)

Sample source: ( [run here](https://ideone.com/wxC7Lb) )

```
import re
str = "?CNTN_CD=A0002400127&PAGE_CD=ET00_1&BLCK_NO=1&CMPT_CD=T0016&TEXT=한글패러미터"
pattern = re.compile(r"[\u0000-\u007F]+")
result = pattern.search(str)
print(result.group(0))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's very helpful.

Comment: @gottaluvflower did the solution solved your problem ? If so, then it is always good to accept the answer. [How TO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> 
>>> import re
>>> str3 = "?CNTN_CD=A0002400127&PAGE_CD=ET00_1&BLCK_NO=1&CMPT_CD=T0016&TEXT=한글패러미터"
>>> pattern = re.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9?=&\-_]+")
>>> result = pattern.search(str3)
>>> print(result.group(0))
?CNTN_CD=A0002400127&PAGE_CD=ET00_1&BLCK_NO=1&CMPT_CD=T0016&TEXT=
>>>
```

i test your code, it works as your expect, my python is v2.7

Comment: Thank you. Your advice is very helpful. print(result.group(0)) was the correct answer. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the string representation of the `_sre.SRE_Match` and it does not guarantee to print all matched characters. I have looked at the CPython source code and found the following [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fbb490fd2f38bd817d99c20c05121ad0168a38ee/Modules/_sre.c#L2314):

```
static PyObject *
match_repr(MatchObject *self)
{
    PyObject *result;
    PyObject *group0 = match_getslice_by_index(self, 0, Py_None);
    if (group0 == NULL)
        return NULL;
    result = PyUnicode_FromFormat(
            "<%s object; span=(%d, %d), match=%.50R>",
            Py_TYPE(self)->tp_name,
            self->mark[0], self->mark[1], group0);
    Py_DECREF(group0);
    return result;
}
```

As you can see, it outputs only 50 first characters of the group.

You may check it with the following regexes:

```
In [52]: print(re.compile('.*').search('a' * 48))
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 48), match='aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'>

In [53]: print(re.compile('.*').search('a' * 49))
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 49), match='aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa>

In [54]: print(re.compile('.*').search('a' * 50))
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 50), match='aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa>
```

As you can see, `match` is always less or equal to 50 characters.

To get the actual matched string you can use `group` method:

```
In [55]: print(re.compile('.*').search('a' * 50).group(0))
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

In [56]: print(len(re.compile('.*').search('a' * 50).group(0)))
50
```